# Why is the bearer token of the FHIR server not recognised by my application?

Tags: php, laravel, bearer-token, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

An external app performs a GET request to my endpoint, using a JWT token to authorise.
This is what I can expect as header and value from their request:

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Accept-Charset | utf-8 |
| Authorization | Bearer |
| Accept | application/fhir+json;q= application/json+fhir;q= |
| User-Agent | HAPI-FHIR/ (FHIR Client; FHIR /DSTU; apache); |
| Accept-Encoding | gzip |

As a response they expect from my app:

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Type | application/fhir+json;charset=utf-8 |

The problem is that when they perform the GET request, I get the following 500 error:

```
Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #1 ($jwt) must be of type string, null given,
```

I am sure they are sending the bearer token.

My app's code:

```
$token = $request->bearerToken();
$decodedToken = JWT::decode($token, $publicKeys);
```

I tried doing the GET request via Postman myself, everything works. Does it have to do with what they expect as a response from me in regarding to the content-type, since it's a FHIR server they are using to make the request?